# It gives an error An object reference is required to access non-static member `GetContainerDetails.Containerdetails.cnum

Tags: c#

I am writing code on container which receives a input from text file and assign its values to the appropriate variables.
Here an error has occured showing
 An object reference is required to access non-static member `GetContainerDetails.Containerdetails.cnum kindly resolve this.

```
using System;
using System.IO;


namespace GetContainerDetails
{
    class Containerdetails
    {
        private string cnum;
        private double length;
        private double height;
        private double depth;
        private double volume;


    // Declare a number of box of type string:
    public string containernum
    {
        get { return cnum; }
        set { cnum = value; }
    }

    // Declare  properties of box of type double:
    public double conlength
    {
        get { return length; }
        set { length = value; }
    }
    public double conheight
    {
        get { return height; }
        set { height = value; }
    }
    public double condepth
    {
        get { return depth; }
        set { depth = value; }
    }
    public double convolume
    {
        get { return volume; }
        set { volume = value; }
    }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/containervalues.txt"))
                {
                    string line;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');
                      cnum=Parts[0];  
                      length=Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);  
                      height=Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);  
                      depth=Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);  
                      volume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                    // what failed?
            }
        }

       }
  }
```

Comment: i know about catch. whats the error its showing

Answer (score 0):

Method `static void Main` cannot access non static members `cnum, length, height, depth and volume`

Either make the method non static or make the members static.

Comment: *Or* create an instance of `Containerdetails`.

Comment: @dcastro creating an instance of `ContainerDetails` changes nothing, you still can't access non-static fields from a static method. Unless you are referring to creating an instance of `ContainerDetails` *inside* the static method which just seems really bad design.

Comment: But you can access the instance's properties. Edit: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Your fields are not static. You are trying to set them from static method. Either make them static, or create instance of `Containerdetails` and use its properties. I think you need the latter:

```
    // create list of containers
    List<Containerdetails> containers = new  List<Containerdetails>();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/containervalues.txt"))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
             // create new instance of container for each line in file
             Containerdetails container = new Containerdetails();
             string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');
             // set non-static properties of container
             container.cocnum = Parts[0];  
             container.colength = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);  
             container.coheight = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);  
             container.codepth = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);  
             container.covolume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);
             // add container to list of containers
             containers.Add(container);
        }
    }
```

---

Side note - If there should be only one container in application, then consider to use application settings to hold application settings in App.config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="num" value="1"/>
  <add key="length" value="12.5"/>
  <add key="height" value="3.5"/>
  <add key="depth" value="10"/>
  <add key="volume" value="60.75"/>
</appSettings>
```

It's easier to support, then line of white space separated numbers. Getting application settings is easy

```
double depth = Double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["depth"]);
```